# Evaluating polynomial with function

Tags: r, polynomials

Im trying to evaluate a polynomial P(x): 
[image: polynomial]

However i dont think im entering the polynomial itself correctly in my function. 
Code for function:

```
directpoly1 <- function(x, coef, seqcoef = seq(coef) - 1) {
  sum(coef*x^seqcoef)
}
directpoly <- function(x, coef) {
  seqcoef <- seq(coef) - 1
  sapply(x, directpoly1, coef, seqcoef)
}
```

Code for using function:

```
directpoly(x=seq(-10,10, length=5000000), rep(c(2,-1),20))
```

Any ideas on how to enter it correctly?

Comment: Try `seqcoef = seq_along(coef)`. This means you will need to include the zero coefficients in the vector `coef`.

Comment: Thx! Can you see if im using the function correctly, so when evaluating P(x) with my function, is P(x) then correctly typed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways of writing your function.

1. With a `sapply` loop. Makes the code more readable and some times faster.
2. With a standard `for` loop.

There is no need to write a separate function outside the function to be called with the `x` values, I have placed that function in the body of the main functions.
Then both functions are tested, with a smaller input vector. As you can see, the `for` loop function is faster.

```
directpoly <- function(x, n = 39, coef = NULL){
  f <- function(y) sum(coef * y^seqcoef)
  if(all(is.null(coef))) coef <- rep(c(2, -1), length.out = n + 1)
  seqcoef <- rev(seq_along(coef) - 1)
  sapply(x, f)
}

directpoly2 <- function(x, n = 39, coef = NULL){
  f <- function(y) sum(coef * y^seqcoef)
  if(all(is.null(coef))) coef <- rep(c(2, -1), length.out = n + 1)
  seqcoef <- rev(seq_along(coef) - 1)
  y <- numeric(length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(y))
    y[i] <- f(x[i])
  y
}

library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(-10, 10, length = 50000)
mb <- microbenchmark(
  Sapply = directpoly(x),
  Forloop = directpoly2(x)
)

autoplot(mb)
```

[image]